# Run antivirus scan - an executable - in a specific drive say c: in python

Tags: python

I am just started learning python so excuse this question is too primary!!

I wanted to run an antivirus scan- an .exe file in a specific drive like c or d.

with some pointers from this site, I came up with this line of python script. but it does full scan. I want to pass an argument to run a scan in a specific drive and not the whole system.

```
subprocess.call([r"C:\Users\Sathish.PV\Downloads\Antivirus_Free_1865.exe"], shell=False)
```

Is there any way to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
arg1, arg2, ... and so on for passing arguments to this.

```
subprocess.call([r"C:\Users\Sathish.PV\Downloads\Antivirus_Free_1865.exe", "arg1", "arg2"], shell=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

As [documented here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), you can indeed pass arguments to the executable:

```
subprocess.call(
    [r"C:\Users\Sathish.PV\Downloads\Antivirus_Free_1865.exe", r"C:\User\Someone\Documents"], 
    shell=False
    )
```

Now what arguments will be supported, in which order, and how they should be formatted depends on the exact application you're calling, so first check your app's doc and do a couple tests in your shell.